# What does the return statement do in this closure?

Tags: javascript

```
function buildFunctions(){
    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        (function(j){
            arr.push(function(){
                console.log(j);
            });
        })(i);
    }   

    return arr;
}
```

In the function above, each time the `for` loop runs it will create a new Execution Context for the IIFE (which is called inside of the for loop). Then inside the IIFE it will push a function inside of the array. The next time the for loop goes around it will again create a new Execution Context for another call to the IIFE.

My question is what happens to the execution context of the first call to the IIFE? Does it still exist in memory or is it popped of the Execution Stack? Since there is no return statement inside of the IIFE's, there will be three Execution Contexts stack on top of each other for each call to the IIFE in the for loop.

Then I am assuming when `return arr;` is called in `buildFunctions` that is the time when those three Execution Contexts for the IIFE's are popped off correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens:

When you execute `var someVar = buildFunctions()`, it will assing an array of 3 **different** anonymous functions to `someVar`.

Each one with it's own context, where `j`'s value is equal to 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

- If you ever call `someVar[0]();` it will output `0`.
- If you ever call `someVar[1]();` it will output `1`.
- If you ever call `someVar[2]();` it will output `2`.

Here you can see the array and `someVar[0]`'s Closure where `j = 0` in chrome's console:

[image]

Comment: Each pushed function has it's own context. They don't have reference to nothing, particularly not to the othes functions' context. When any pushed fn is executed, it remains in it's execution context, which includes a *local var* called *j* that has it's value set

Comment: Ohh ok! But how do each of the anonymous functions in the array know which value of j to use when they are executed?

Comment: Because each function was created in a context (which was created by the IIFE). That context defines the value of `j`. You have created 3 different `j` vars, if you modify one of them, the others remain the same.

Comment: Ohh ok. That makes sense now! Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe this jsfiddle I've created helps you out a little more :) http://jsfiddle.net/jormaechea/euaf06x3/1/